# How can I combine two functions that differ only in the types declared

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am writing a mex function to grab an image from an FLI camera. The image can have varying bit depth (either 8 or 16 bits), so I've had to write two functions that differ only in the types declared. My Question: How Can I combine the following functions to eliminate as much code duplication as possible?

```
mxArray* grabFrame16Bit(flidev_t device, long imageWidth, long imageHeight) {
    long imageSize = imageWidth*imageHeight;
    uint16_t *image = (uint16_t *) mxCalloc(imageSize, sizeof(uint16_t));
    int iRow, ind;
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < imageHeight; iRow++) {
        ind = iRow*imageWidth;
        fli::checkReturn(FLIGrabRow(device, image+ind, imageWidth),
                         "fliTestSnapMex:FLIGrabRow"); 
    }

    mxArray *outMat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(imageWidth, imageHeight, mxREAL);
    double *imageOut = mxGetPr(outMat);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        imageOut[i] = (double) image[i];
    mxFree(image);
    image = NULL;
    return outMat;
}

mxArray* grabFrame8Bit(flidev_t device, long imageWidth, long imageHeight) {
    long imageSize = imageWidth*imageHeight;
    uint8_t *image = (uint8_t *) mxCalloc(imageSize, sizeof(uint8_t));
    int iRow, ind;
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < imageHeight; iRow++) {
        ind = iRow*imageWidth;
        fli::checkReturn(FLIGrabRow(device, image+ind, imageWidth),
                         "fliTestSnapMex:FLIGrabRow"); }

    mxArray *outMat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(imageWidth, imageHeight, mxREAL);
    double *imageOut = mxGetPr(outMat);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        imageOut[i] = (double) image[i];
    mxFree(image);
    image = NULL;
    return outMat;
}
```

Here declarations for the one custom function I wrote, along with the other API functions, in case you are not familiar with the FLI API, or the MATLAB mex/mx API.

```
// allocates memory
void *mxCalloc(mwSize n, mwSize size);

// checks for an error
void fli::checkReturn(long returnCode, char * errorId); 

// grabs a row of the image
long FLIGrabRow(flidev_t device, void * buffer, size_t width); 

// creates a double matrix
mxArray *mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mwSize m, mwSize n, mxComplexity complexFlag); 

// gives a pointer to the data in the matrix
double *mxGetPr(const mxArray *pm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of templates!

A naive approach is to just replace all the occurrences of a type and replace it with a template type parameter.

```
template <class T>
mxArray* grabFrame(flidev_t device, long imageWidth, long imageHeight) {
    long imageSize = imageWidth*imageHeight;
    T *image = (T*) mxCalloc(imageSize, sizeof(T));
    int iRow, ind;
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < imageHeight; iRow++) {
        ind = iRow*imageWidth;
        fli::checkReturn(FLIGrabRow(device, image+ind, imageWidth),
                         "fliTestSnapMex:FLIGrabRow"); 
    }

    mxArray *outMat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(imageWidth, imageHeight, mxREAL);
    double *imageOut = mxGetPr(outMat[0]);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        imageOut[i] = (double) image[i];
    mxFree(image);
    image = NULL;
    return outMat;
}
```

Since type of template parameter can't be deduced out of function parameters, you have to specify it explicitly with each call:

```
mxArray* array = grabFrame<uint8_t>(device, width, height);
```

EDIT: your code didn't have return statement, so I allowed myself to add it.

Comment: Also, `template <class T>` and `template <typename T>` mean the exact same thing to the compiler.  It's a matter of style, but in this case I'd prefer `typename` since `T` is probably not a class type.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename PixelType>
mxArray* grabFrame(flidev_t device, long imageWidth, long imageHeight) {
    long imageSize = imageWidth*imageHeight;
    PixelType *image = (PixelType *) mxCalloc(imageSize, sizeof(PixelType));
    int iRow, ind;
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < imageHeight; iRow++) {
        ind = iRow*imageWidth;
        fli::checkReturn(FLIGrabRow(device, image+ind, imageWidth),
                     "fliTestSnapMex:FLIGrabRow"); 
    }

    mxArray *outMat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(imageWidth, imageHeight, mxREAL);
    double *imageOut = mxGetPr(outMat[0]);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
        imageOut[i] = (double) image[i];
    mxFree(image);
    image = NULL;
}
```

The call

```
 grabFrame<uint8_t>(....)
```

or

```
 grabFrame<uint16_t>(...)
```